# I can't install C++ extension for Visual studio code

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I can't install C++ extension for Visual studio code. When I try to install it I get message of error:

```
Error while installing 'C/C++' extension. Please check the log for more details.
```

And when I checked logs to had seen next message:

```
2023-06-29 14:03:55.273 [error] Download: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
    at gt.download (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:81:160122)
    at async j.y (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:82:20937)
    at async j.h (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:82:19006)
2023-06-29 14:03:55.310 [error] net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED: Download: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
    at gt.download (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:81:160122)
    at async j.y (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:82:20937)
    at async j.h (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:82:19006)
```

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.

How can I install C++ extension?

I tried reinstalling VS Code but it didn't work.

P.S. I have GCC 11.3.0.

Comment: Your Internet connection appears to be broken. At least according to Google when searching `[error] net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED`. This is not a C++ nor a programming/software development problem at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure GCC is installed

Although you'll use VS Code to edit your source code, you'll compile the source code on Linux using the g++ compiler. You'll also use GDB to debug. These tools are not installed by default on Ubuntu, so you have to install them. Fortunately, that's easy.

First, check to see whether GCC is already installed. To verify whether it is, open a Terminal window and enter the following command:

```
gcc -v
```

I have the same OS (Ubuntu 22.04). I just check out, and I have installed the C++ extension for VS Code. Furthermore, I ran a simple helloworld.cpp, and I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};
    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

And the log

```
[Running] cd "/home/piercel/cplusplus/projects/helloworld/" && g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld && "/home/piercel/cplusplus/projects/helloworld/"helloworld
Hello C++ World from VS Code and the C++ extension! 

[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.584 seconds
```

Comment: Compiling code properly seems to have very little to do with a network error.

Comment: I have GCC 11.3.0.